# Override modules phtml in luma Theme

Tags: magento2, overrides, phtml, luma-theme

I'am using **Luma theme** and I tried to override some **`phtml`** from `module_catalog`.
In luma theme folder which is in `vendor/theme-frontend-luma` in `/Magento_Catalog` I created the same path as **phtml** form that I tried to override and it's not working.

Is it possible to do that in Luma theme? or the only way is to create my own theme in app folder to override file?

Comment: have you got answer?

Comment: I am facing same issue, got any answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can not change directly in `vendon/magento/theme-frontend-luma` folder instead of you have to create new theme in `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>`, you can refer magento docs  [How to create new theme in magento 2 ?](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)

Once you create theme then you can override `phtml` file in your theme over here:

```
app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/{file.phtml}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override using this path `app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/{file.phtml}`

You can also refer this blog. [Overwrite module phtml file and re-write in own theme Magento 2](http://blog.trimantra.com/overwrite-module-phtml-file-re-write-theme-magento-2/)

let me know if not work.

Comment: so in my case if i am using luma theme i need to create in designa folder another folder called luma? because i don't have a custom theme or something, i work with luma

Comment: yes. you have to create folder in app/design/frontend/{vender}/{your_theme}/..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can overrride this way even if you can it's not ideal, you should create your own custom theme in `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>` which inherits from Luma so any changes that you make will override Luma theme's functionality for rest it will use default luma styles/functionality.

Make sure to change theme in admin panel and it's deployed correctly through `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command. Further read on [Setting Up Custom Theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can override template and block using layout handler

use to remove old block

```
<referenceBlock name="blockname" remove="true"/>
```

and then add your block

here is example

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="adjustments" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="creditmemo_totals">
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Creditmemo\Create\Adjustments" name="Company_fee" template="Company_Custom::creditmemo/ktplfee.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```